# How can I select multiple date partition in using replaceWhere clause in Azure databricks

Tags: csv, pyspark, azure-databricks, partition

I am trying to only overwrite selected *partitions* using `replaceWhere` . Unfortunately the partition schema is using `Year`, `Month` and  `Day`.

I have tried the following code, but **it `overwrite` everything**, and not only the selected dates.

And it does not throw any error message.

```
DateFrom = df_raw_mango.agg({"file_date": "min"}).collect()[0][0]
DateTo = df_raw_mango.agg({"file_date": "max"}).collect()[0][0]

condition = f"concat(col('Year'), col('Month'), col('Day')) >= '{DateFrom}' AND concat(col('Year'), col('Month'), col('Day')) <= '{DateTo}'"


df_raw_mango.coalesce(1).write.format('csv') \
                        .option("replaceWhere", condition).mode('overwrite') \
                        .option('header','true') \
                        .option('delimiter',',') \
                        .partitionBy(['Year','Month','Day','file_name']) \
                        .save(f'/mnt/Fruits/Mango/Green')
```

I even tried to put partition `file_date` and do it like that, but without success :

```
condition = f"file_date >= '{DateFrom}' AND file_date <= '{DateTo}'"
.coalesce(1).write.format('csv') \
                    .partitionBy(['Year','Month','Day','file_name','file_date']) \
                    .option("replaceWhere", condition).mode('overwrite') \
                    .option('header','true') \
                    .option('delimiter',',') \
                    .save(f'/mnt/Fruits/Mango/Green/')
```

I am on **databricks 10.4**. Documentation says `replaceWhere` works on **>9.1** https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/selective-overwrite.html#arbitrary-selective-overwrite-with-replacewhere&language-python. But not working for me.

Instead, i have to *delete partitions* and `append` only.

Answer (score 0):

Neverminds, it seems that it is a datalake feature. Does not work with CSV. I overlooked documentation.